# What data areaCode and metroCode columns contain for in maxmind?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

As i inderstand area code - is regional telephone code, right?
What for metro code column stays for then?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A metro code is a zip code like in the states, e.g. 24100

Answer (score 6):

Metro Code is a DMA code like "803" for Los Angeles, as defined by Google AdWords. Area code is, indeed, the telephone prefix after the country code.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/cities-DMAregions

Comment: The information behind the link is gone and now just states
"Please contact The Nielsen Company directly for DMA data."

Maybe the maxmind doc helps a bit instead? https://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-dotnet/doc/v2.7.1/html/P_MaxMind_GeoIP2_Model_Location_MetroCode.htm